# Acquiring spans in nested divs with XPath in HtmlUnit

Tags: html, xpath, htmlunit

I am a beginner with XPath and am having trouble fetching the values I want from a website. I am using this together with HtmlUnit.
This is the format that I am facing:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <body>
    <div>
    <script>
    ..more scripts..
    <div>
       <header>
       <script>
       <script>
       <div>
         <div>
           <div>
           <div>
             <table>
               <thead>
               <tbody>
                 <tr>
                   <td>
                     <a>
                       <span>
                         <span> Random info to retrieve </span>
                   <td>
                     <a>
                       <span>
                         <span> Random info to retrieve </span>
                   <td>
                     <a>
                       <span>
                         <span> Random info to retrieve </span>
                 <tr>
                   <td>
                     <a>
                       <span>
                         <span> Random info to retrieve </span>
                   <td>
                     <a>
                       <span>
                         <span> Random info to retrieve </span>
                   <td>
                     <a>
                       <span>
                         <span> Random info to retrieve </span>
                   ..
```

I want to extract the values from  but every try so far has failed.
I have tried to only find span by using the following xpath:

```
//span
```

but then I only get back a span which is located under the header which I am not interested in. I also tried:

```
//body//div[2]//div[1]//div[1]//div[2]//table//tbody//tr//td//a//span
```

which returned nothing.
I have also tried other paths without success. Can anyone help me with what the correct path to acquire all the spans under the table would be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I realised now after posting the question that the span has an additional //span at the end, tried using //span//span etc but did not work either(I edited in the extra <span> into the question).

Comment: What values do you have in mind? Are you talking about the OuterHtml, InnerHtml, Text? `//span/text()` is this what you want? Please explain. And could you link the page in question?

Comment: @wp78de I updated the question so the information that I want to retrieve is more clear. So, what I want to retrieve is the text between the two <span>

Comment: Like that: [`//span/span`](http://1w.tf/eI2qh)? Do not add // between each and every path.